# In ag-grid, is there a known issue with filter values for dateFrom, dateTo, dateFromCondition, and dateToCondition?

Tags: ag-grid

I want to allow users to filter a grid, and then save the filtering options they have chosen so they can then use that filter subsequently.

I am able to extract the current filter data by using

```
optionObject.api.getFilterInstance(field_name_for_column);
```

I see different values in the returned object based on whether the column is a text column, a number column or a date column.

The text columns seem to use filterText and filterConditionText for the 2 allowed filter values.

The number columns seem to use filterNumber, filterNumberTo, filterNumberCondition and filterNumberConditionTo for the allowed filters, where the "To" values are used for range checks.

The date columns seem to have the same sort of setup (dateFrom, dateTo, dateConditionFrom, dateConditionTo) as the numbers.

However, when I print the values, dateFromCondition and dateToCondition seem to have the values from dateFrom and dateTo.

For example, if I do 2 date ranges:

```
01/01/2004 to 02/01/2004 OR
02/01/2004 to 03/01/2004
```

The values returned in the filter are:

```
dateFrom = 01/01/2004
dateTo = 02/01/2004
dateFromCondtion = 01/01/2004
dateToCondition = 02/01/2004
```

Am I misunderstanding how these values are intended to be used? Or is this a known issue in ag-grid?

I am using the standard agDateColumnFilter setting for filter and have provided a dateFilter routine to do the comparator (per the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

> Am I misunderstanding how these values are intended to be used? Or is this a known issue in ag-grid?

`ConditionalFilter` - configured via `getFilterInstance` and `setModel` functions, so - you are be able to retrieve `conditionalValue` from filter instance.

```
let dateFilterInstance = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance("yourDateField");
console.log(dateFilterInstance.conditionValue);
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The issue I see is that the values returned do not seem to match what I entered. I don't have a problem getting values out; I just don't see the values I expect.